# Access raw error object in Nuxt error page

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

The Nuxt.js error page, as described [here](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/views/), is passed an `error` property which can be used to figure out what the error was and display something appropriate.

However, the error object passed looks something like:

```
{
  message:"Cannot read property 'nonexistentThing' of undefined",
  statusCode:"TypeError"
}
```

I would like to take action on the error page (hitting an error-reporting API) which ideally would have access to the underlying error object including the backtrace etc.

Is there a way to either

- access this from the error page; or
- make a plugin which intercepts the error while Nuxt’s own error-handling is in flight?

Answer (score 0):

Although I didn't found a way to access the underlying error object I've found this error method from nuxt where you can throw your exception which finally gets displayed in Nuxt's error page. You can access this error method in the context object (https://nuxtjs.org/api/context/)

An example error including the exception could be this:

```
export default {
  asyncData ({ params, error }) {
    return axios.get(`https://my-api/posts/${params.id}`)
      .then((res) => {
        return { title: res.data.title }
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Post not found', myError: e })
      })
  }
}
```

So then you could process the exception in the error page like this

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 v-if="error.statusCode === 404">Page not found</h1>
    <h1 v-else>An error occurred</h1>
    <nuxt-link to="/">Home page</nuxt-link>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['error'],
  mounted() {
    const { statusCode, message, myError } = this.error;
    // send myError to error-reporting API
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you – I think this is certainly useful. However, I don’t think it’s going to work for my use-case because I don’t know ahead of time where the error will occur, and so I wouldn’t know where to put the call to `error()`.